# if multiple variable are empty jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Help why is this not working. Im trying to check lots of inputs if they are empty, Im getting SyntaxError error.

```
if (fname  === '') || (lname  === ''){
  alert('Text-field is empty.');
  return false;
}
```

Comment: That logical or is just sitting in the middle of nowhere. `if(fname === '' || lname === '')`

Comment: What made you think `if (fname  === '') || (lname  === '') {` is valid syntax?

Answer (score 5):

```
if ((fname  === '') || (lname  === '')) {
  alert('Text-field is empty.');
  return false;
}
```

All if-statement conditions must be wrapped in parentheses.

Comment: Sometimes if you stare at your code too long you miss obvious errors... Happens to me all the time.